# Android notification bigcontentview : different layout on expand and collepse

Tags: android, notifications, customization

I have some problem with expand and collapse of notification bigcontentview.

When notification is top of the list of notification , there have expand view as stated in android document, but when notification is not on the top of the list of notification, notification view become weird. I show you in the figure

(Sorry for hiding content in image)

**(1. collapsed view)**

[image]

In this notification contents become invisible

**(2. Expanded view)**

[image]

after expand it all content visible, i know that this is the correct behavior.

but I want to change layout as notification get collapsed. so i can change the layout and there content visible

**Is there any solution of it? how can i get the notification is collapsed or expanded ?** and how can i change layout of it during expand and collapse? So all content visible.

**Is there any way to add layout differently for expanded and collapsed notification?**

**My code is below** :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void updateNotification(String text) {

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent5 = null;

        if (mRemoteViews == null) {
            Log.d("LOG", "mRemoteViews is null");
            if (Base.sharedPref.getBoolean("firsttimenotifiation", false)) {

                mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.custom_notification);
            } else {
                if (isCurrentBuildabove16()) {
                    mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.customizenotification);
                } else {
                    mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.customnotification);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (MusicList.MusicFrom != MusicList.FromNotification) {
            if (mState == State.Paused || mState == State.Stopped || mState == State.Stopappnotification) {


                try {
                    Log.e("LOG", "State.Paused || State.Stopped");
                    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                            R.drawable.playdetailfornoti);

                }catch (Exception e) {}
            } else if (mState == State.Playing) {
                try {
                    Log.e("LOG", "State.Playing");
                    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                            R.drawable.pushdetail);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            } else if (mState == State.Retrieving) {
                try {

                    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                            R.drawable.playdetailfornoti);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } else {
                try {
                        mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                R.drawable.pushdetail);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(CLOSE_NOTIFICATION);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(ACTION_STOP);
        intent.putExtra(CLICKFROM, APPNOTIFICATION);


        Intent newintent = new Intent(this, Splace.class);
        newintent.putExtra("newsId", MusicList.CurrentMusicEntity._id);

        newintent.putExtra("playfrom", "detailnotification");
        newintent
                .putExtra("message", MusicList.CurrentMusicEntity.scrape_title);
        newintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        newintent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                REQUEST_CODE_STOP, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent1, 0);
        pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                REQUEST_CODE_STOP, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                REQUEST_CODE_STOP, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                newintent, 0);
        pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                REQUEST_CODE_STOP, intent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forward, pendingIntent2);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.backword, pendingIntent3);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playertitle, contentIntent);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playernewspapaer,
                contentIntent);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playerimage, contentIntent);

        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playpush, pendingIntent);

        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, pendingIntent1);

    // coded differently for those below 16(which is not supported bigview) and above 16 api level
        if (isCurrentBuildabove16()) {
            mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent4)
                    .setPriority(Notification.FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())// .setContent(mRemoteViews)
                    .setOngoing(false).build();

            mNotification.bigContentView = mRemoteViews;
        } else {
            mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent4)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContent(mRemoteViews).setOngoing(false).build();
        }

        if (!Base.isAppForeground) {

                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);    
        }
    }
```

Please Help Me Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved my issue Check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021665/android-multiple-notification-avoid-blinking-while-updating
I solved blinking issue as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm setting both big and normal view of notification at the same time, and it allows to switch between the two by expanding and collapsing it.

However there's another issue with big view: it flickering every time I update notification if I set big view..

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021665/android-multiple-notification-avoid-blinking-while-updating

Comment: I see your solution Mayur, but if I kept reference to Notification I created and update it's fields, it seemed not to get updated.

Comment: You have to update all latest information in the notification after one time creation of it.  Means in `else` condition

`else { 
          //here you have to change latest info otherwise it will not affest in notification
            mNotification1.deleteIntent = pendingIntent1;
            // this will solve the deleteintent issue 
            mNotification1.contentView = mRemoteViews1; 
    } `