# Android multiple notification avoid blinking while updating

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am working on such application which is using multiple notification.where each notification have playpause icon which perform play/pause of music player. but there is odd behavior with updating that notifications which keep blinking while updating it.

My Code is below

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void UpdateNotificationfunction(int currentNotificationNo) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent5 = null;

        if (mRemoteViews1 == null || newRemoteview) {
            Log.d("LOG", "mRemoteViews is null 123");

            mRemoteViews1 = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.custom_notification);
            newRemoteview = false;
        } else {

                if (mState == State.Paused || mState == State.Stopped) {
                    try {

                        mRemoteViews1.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                R.drawable.playdetailfornoti);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                } else if (mState == State.Playing) {
                    try {

                        mRemoteViews1.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                R.drawable.pushdetail);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else if (mState == State.Retrieving) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("LOG", "else Retrieving");
                        mRemoteViews1.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                R.drawable.playdetailfornoti);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Log.e("LOG", "else");
                        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(_context)) {
                            mRemoteViews1.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                    R.drawable.pushdetail);
                        }
                        else {
                            mRemoteViews1.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpush,
                                    R.drawable.playdetailfornoti);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
            }

        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);
        intent.removeExtra("playposition");
        intent.putExtra("playposition", currentNotificationNo);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(CLOSE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(ACTION_STOP);
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY_NOTIFICATION_START);
        intent5.removeExtra("playposition");
        intent1.removeExtra("playposition"); // here i remove put extra 
        intent5.putExtra("playposition", currentNotificationNo);
        intent1.putExtra("playposition", currentNotificationNo);// here i add put extra with current notification id
        Log.e("LOG", "poistionset || " + currentNotificationNo);

        Intent newintent = new Intent(this, Splace.class);
        newintent.putExtra("newsId",MusicList.CurrentNotificationEntity._id);
        newintent.putExtra("playposition", currentNotificationNo);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent2,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent3,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), currentNotificationNo, newintent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent4,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent5 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                currentNotificationNo, intent5,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mRemoteViews1.setTextViewText(R.id.playertitle,
                MusicList.CurrentNotificationEntity.scrape_title);
        mRemoteViews1.setViewVisibility(R.id.playernewspapaer, View.VISIBLE);
        mRemoteViews1.setViewVisibility(R.id.forward, View.VISIBLE);
        mRemoteViews1.setViewVisibility(R.id.backword, View.VISIBLE);

        mRemoteViews1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forward, pendingIntent2);
        mRemoteViews1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.backword, pendingIntent3);

        mRemoteViews1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playertitle, contentIntent);
        mRemoteViews1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playernewspapaer,
                contentIntent);
        mRemoteViews1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playerimage, contentIntent);

            //if (mNotification1 == null) {
         mNotification1 = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent1).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContent(mRemoteViews1).setOngoing(false).build();
    /*}
    else {
            mNotification1.contentView = mRemoteViews1;
    }*/ //this comment solve my same id issue , I have put this for avoid blinking of notification
                        .setContent(mRemoteViews1).setOngoing(false).build();


        mNotificationManager.notify(currentNotificationNo, mNotification1);
    }
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a tries a lot, I found the solution for  blinking issue and duplicate  deleteintent issue

```
 if (mNotification1 == null) {
     // create when notification not avalible
         mNotification1 = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent1).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContent(mRemoteViews1).setOngoing(false).build();
    }
    else {
          // this code will solve the blink issue
            mNotification1.deleteIntent = pendingIntent1; // this will solve the deleteintent issue
            mNotification1.contentView = mRemoteViews1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide a single `PendingIntent` that will be sent when the notification is deleted by the user. This `PendingIntent` is provided in the call to `setDeleteIntent()` when constructing the notification. You can't get Android to send 5 `PendingIntent`s when your notification is deleted by the user.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and Sorry for some mistake.I got solution after comment some code later on,which i updated , but there is other problem notification blinking issue , i have updated information and question also please see the information and suggest me what to do?